# There exists a sequence $(y_n) \in \ell_2$ such that $(x_n / y_n) \in \ell_2$ for every $ (x_n) \in \ell_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to figure out if there exists a sequence $(y_n) \in \ell_2$ such that $(x_n / y_n) \in \ell_2$ for every $(x_n) \in \ell_1$. There some obvious reductions to this problem: we have to consider $y_n \neq 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, $(y_n) \notin \ell_1$, because it would imply $(1)_n = (y_n/y_n)_n \in \ell_2.$ I think it is necessary that $(y_n) \notin \ell_p$ for any $p<2,$ but I don't know if this condition is sufficient.

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Can the sequence $y$ depend on $x$ or should the same $y$ work for all $x$?

Comment: If $(y_n)$ depends on $(x_n)$ is trivial as long as you can define a square root. I would like to know if there exists a $(y_n)$ that works for all $x.$

Comment: Assume some $y$ works: then $y \rightarrow 0$. Take $x_n=\sqrt{|y_n|} \in \ell^1$. Then $\frac{x_n}{|y_n|}=|y_n|^{-1/2}$ is unbounded thus not $\ell^1$.

Comment: @Mindlack $|y_n|^{-1/2}$ is definitively bounded for $n\to\infty$

Comment: @Mindlack if $(y_n) \in \ell_2$ and $x_n = \sqrt{|y_n|}$, then $(x_n) \notin \ell_1.$ You can assure that $x_n = |y_n|^2 \in \ell_2.$ !

Comment: Ok, maybe this would work: If there exists such an $y \in \ell_2,$ observe that $|y_n|^2 \in \ell_1$, so $x_n = |y_n|^2/y_n \in \ell_1,$ but $|x_n| = |y_n|$, so $(y_n) \in \ell_1$, and this cannot happen.

Comment: @Javier González: yes, I was very mistaken. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a long-winded, but I think it works: Suppose such a sequence $y = (y_n)$ exists, then we may define $T : \ell^1\to \ell^2$ by
$$
T((x_n)) = (x_n/y_n)
$$
We claim that $T$ is continuous: Suppose $x^k \to x$ in $\ell^1$ and $T(x^k) \to z$ in $\ell^2$, then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} |z_n - \frac{x^k_n}{y_n}|^2 \leq \lim_{k\to \infty} \|z - T(x^k)\|_2^2 = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \lim_{k\to \infty} |y_nz_n - x^k_n|^2 = 0
$$
But
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} |x_n - x^k_n| \leq \lim_{k\to \infty} \|x - x^k\|_1 = 0
$$
So
$$
z_n = \frac{x_n}{y_n} \quad\forall n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
Hence, $T(x) = z$, so $T$ is bounded by the closed graph theorem. Hence, there is $M> 0$ such that
$$
\|T(x)\|_2 \leq M\|x\|_1 \quad\forall x\in \ell^1
$$
Applying this to the `standard basis' $e_n \in \ell^1$, we conclude that
$$
\frac{1}{|y_n|^2} \leq M \quad\forall n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
Since $M > 0$, this implies that
$$
|y_n|^2 \geq \frac{1}{M} \quad\forall n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
contradicting the assumption that $(y_n) \in \ell^2$. Thus, no such sequence $(y_n)$ can exist.